# In Photoshop, how can I open up a view (in the same window) with another zoom level?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When drawing pixel art in Photoshop, I like to have the zoom level really high.  Is there a way to also have a regular-level zoom (or perhaps an outer zoom) in another part of the window, so that I can see how the regular zoom will look as I work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look under the `Window > Arrange` menu for "New Window for [document name]" (it will be at the bottom). That opens the same document in a second window. Then you can tile the two and zoom in on one of them.

This is a very common technique when working in Photoshop for retouching as well as drawing.

Comment: You're welcome! It's one of those non-obvious, not-easy-to-find features that you can't really live without if you work a lot in Photoshop.

Comment: Do both views update in real time?

Comment: Absolutely. They are views of the same open document, not a copy. Works the same way in InDesign and Illustrator.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but the new answer to this is Window> Navigator. That will bring up a small overview screen you can watch while you're zoomed in

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!