# Resizing rectangle in Fireworks without losing sharpness

Tags: adobe-fireworks, resize

I resized an icon from 128x128 to 40x40 pixels.  The snap-to-pixel option is turned on, but the icon is still "blurry".

Original (128x128):
[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/641/cal128.png/]

Resized (40x40):
[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/cal40k.png/]

How can I resize my image and retain sharpness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where it's a good idea to plan things out beforehand and do some math. There is no way to take a 128x128 image and reduce it to 40x40 such that your lines will end up as whole pixels, nor aligned with pixel boundaries. You also can't take a one-pixel line, reduce it to 40/128 (5/16ths) of its original size and still have a one-pixel line that's correctly scaled. Your individual calendar "boxes" are 31 pixels wide by 16 tall. They would have to reduce to 9.6875 pixels wide by 5 tall. That's impossible, so FW has to fudge it.

The 26-pixel top banner has to scale to 8.125 pixels, which throws off all your horizontal lines, because FW can't put them on pixel boundaries *and* maintain proportions. FW has no choice but to try its best to approximate, using whatever algorithm it's using to throw away pixels, the appearance of the original. It doesn't do a great job, but you're giving it an impossible task.

If you start at 160x160 and reduce that to 40x40, you have a much better chance of getting an acceptable result, but you have to work with multiples of 4 pixels to get the best product. To get a clean 40x40 icon, I would create it at that size to have pixel by pixel control over placement. Use [this trick](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/in-photoshop-how-can-i-open-up-a-view-in-the-same-window-with-another-zoom-le) to make it easier to work with.