# Free Transform in Photoshop Elements 10 without anti-aliasing

Tags: anti-aliasing, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am re-asking this question for Photoshop Elements 10 :
[How can I resize an image without anti-aliasing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/how-can-i-resize-an-image-without-anti-aliasing)

I want the same result as the user got here- the ability to change a layer's angle and scale without having photoshop try to smooth the image for me (I'm working with pixel art). The only issue is that there is no "Interpolate Image" option in the general preferences tab like in other photoshops. The only area I can even access the "Nearest Neighbor" option is in the Image Resize tab, and that doesn't allow me to operate within a specific layer or to change the angle at all.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could copy the part of the image you want to resize into a new image; resize that image using "Nearest Neighbor" interpolation; then copy it back into your original image.

But that doesn't help if you need to rotate. This might just be one of the features that Elements leaves out...

Comment: I guess that's the case, a shame really. Thanks for letting me know though, appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

One way that might work better is to convert the item that you want to resize and rotate to a smart object. If you do not want to leave the item as a smart object, then you could re-rasterize it once you are finished with the transformations.

The results will vary depending on the type and complexity of your image. This method has worked well for me with line drawings, shapes, and shadows, but not as well for photographs. I hope this is helpful!