# Converting bitmap to vector

Tags: vector, bitmap

I have a small (32x32) grey rectangle that I converted into bitmap:

[image]

I want to convert the black areas into vector polygons.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You can trace that bitmap

Answer (score 0):

File Place image >
Click on Image Trace > (select default)
Click on expand >
Right click and ungroup >
And select the square and fill the color

[image]

Download the vector file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZRlNfWDREWFlYcUk)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not solving my problem. I want the exact same result as the bitmap picture.

Comment: may i know what is missing then? It has converted whole bitmap to vector

Comment: Image trace isn't great for pixel-art or bitmaps like this if you want any accuracy. You can instead [use an object mosaic](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/79248/52050).