# Is there a way to perfectly scale up an image, by a factor of a square number?

Tags: resize, image-editing

What I mean is, if I double the length and width of an image, then I could take every pixel and make it a 2x2 square, thus enlarging the image, but not losing any pixel data.

When I tried doing this in some image editing programs, it did the thing they always do, where it changes the colors of some pixels to make it all blend in. But I would like for it to perfectly scale it up.

Does anyone know of a software (preferably free) that could do this?

Comment: It would make the image look more block-y because every pixel would now be 4 pixels. Is that what you want?

Comment: Well, what I was hoping for was to perfectly scale the picture up, then just touch it up a little. I'm making game art for one of my arcade-style games, so that isn't a huge problem. I'm scaling up the image because I want the ability to make the game full screen, in which the current size of the image would end up being a little blurry, since I drew it for a specific game size.

Comment: Images can't generically be scaled up perfectly because there is no way for the processor to know what *should* go in those extra 3 pixels. What image editor do is do their best guess (usually averaging). So unless you want everything more block-y, no, there's not a software that does this

Comment: Photoshop can do this. Just scale up by whole hundreds of percentages (200%, 300%, etc.) and use Nearest Neighbour sampling.

Comment: Does [How can I 'blow up' small pixel art?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65374/how-can-i-blow-up-small-pixel-art/) answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I 'blow up' small pixel art?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65374/how-can-i-blow-up-small-pixel-art)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you simply need to reescale your image using "nearest neighbour", instead of bicubic or other algorithm.

If you have an image of 100x100px and you scale it up to 200x200 using nearest neighbour it will look the same as if you are using a 200% zoom.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want. https://www.on1.com/store/perfect-resize-9-premium-edition/

Perfect square, as said above, just makes it blocky,