# Is it possible to have a 'live preview' in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Photoshop, how can I open up a view (in the same window) with another zoom level?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/in-photoshop-how-can-i-open-up-a-view-in-the-same-window-with-another-zoom-le)

I'm working on small 16x16px icons. I'm usually zoomed right in working pixel by pixel. It would be hugely useful to have a 'live preview' at 100% scale, so I don't have to manually zoom in and out all the time to see how it looks. Is this possible?

Comment: This has already been answered here:http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/in-photoshop-how-can-i-open-up-a-view-in-the-same-window-with-another-zoom-le

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Window>Arrange>New Window for ImageName.png
Window>Arrange>Tile

Now you can zoom one to original size and with the other you can work. Have fun!